# Cannot Resolve Symbol R Upon New Project Creation

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There seem to be many threads addressing this question, but none have worked for me. My problem is that whenever I start a new project, R is highlighted red, and the project will not run.

Luckily - for the sake of simplicity - I have not implemented any code, all the code in the project is simply the code created by the creation of a new project:

```
package com.abc.android.unnamed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

The XML file remains unchanged:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.abc.android.unnamed.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried:

- Deleting the project files and creating a new project
- Doing Build > Clean Project, then Build > Rebuild Project

All of which yield the same result.

Each time, the Gradle Console displays:

[image: gradle Console display]

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I fixed my problem. My antivirus (Bitdefender) was not giving access to aapt2.exe, as seen in the error from the Gradle Console.

[image: Bitdefender Access Image]

This was not immediately obvious as I did not see any notification that it was blocked. Additionally, sample code was able to resolve R without any fuss, so I was confused why I was not able to get it working. After allowing aapt2.exe access, with a Gradle rebuild, there is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna add this here as i can't comment yet, for anyone experiencing the same issue.
I think Windows Defender does the same thing. As soon as i shut off the real-time protection the symbol R was resolved.